# using UrlRewriteFilter shows This webpage has a redirect loop

Tags: tomcat, redirect, url-rewriting, urlrewriter

I am using `UrlRewriteFilter` to convert `example.com` to `www.example.com`

```
<urlrewrite>
    <rule>
      <name>Canonical Hostnames</name>
      <condition name="host" operator="notequal">^example.com</condition>
      <condition name="host" operator="notequal">^$</condition>
      <from>^/(.*)</from>
      <to type="redirect" last="true">http://www.example.com/$1</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

When i browse `example.com` browser shows `This webpage has a redirect loop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `<condition name="host" operator="notequal">^example.com</condition>`

Replace the above with one of the following

`<condition name="host" operator="equal">^example\.com</condition>`

`<condition name="host" operator="notequal">^www\.example\.com</condition>`

Comment: but the problem with this is `http://example.com/resetpassword/?user=2560256&token=1233` is redirected to `http://example.com/resetpassword`